# Add a previous row value of another column grouped by same column (soccer data)

Tags: r, data.table

Data

```
Country League         Season   Month   monthDay    weekDay      Time   HomeTeam    AwayTeam    FTHG    FTAG    FTR HomeTeamPoints  AwayTeamPoints
Denmark Superliga   2015/2016   July          19    Sunday   12:30:00   Odense         Hobro    3       0       H          3               0
Denmark Superliga   2015/2016   July          24    Friday   17:00:00   Hobro        Aalborg    0       1       A          0               3
Denmark Superliga   2015/2016   August         2    Sunday   17:00:00   Brondby        Hobro    0       2       A          0               3
Denmark Superliga   2015/2016   August         8    Saturday 15:00:00   Hobro         Viborg    1       1       D          1               0
Denmark Superliga   2015/2016   August        17    Monday   18:00:00   Sonderjyske    Hobro    3       0       H          0               3
Denmark Superliga   2015/2016   August        21    Friday   17:30:00   Hobro  Nordsjaelland    1       3       A          1               1
Denmark Superliga   2015/2016   August        30    Sunday   19:30:00   Midtjylland    Hobro    2       0       H          7               3
```

Desired output:

```
Country League         Season   Month   monthDay    weekDay      Time   HomeTeam    AwayTeam    FTHG    FTAG    FTR HomeTeamPoints  AwayTeamPoints HomeTeamTotalPoints  AwayTeamTotalPoints
Denmark Superliga   2015/2016   July          19    Sunday   12:30:00   Odense         Hobro    3       0       H          3               0                                   0
Denmark Superliga   2015/2016   July          24    Friday   17:00:00   Hobro        Aalborg    0       1       A          0               3              0
Denmark Superliga   2015/2016   August         2    Sunday   17:00:00   Brondby        Hobro    0       2       A          0               3                                   3  
Denmark Superliga   2015/2016   August         8    Saturday 15:00:00   Hobro         Viborg    1       1       D          1               0              4
Denmark Superliga   2015/2016   August        17    Monday   18:00:00   Sonderjyske    Hobro    3       0       H          0               3                                   4
Denmark Superliga   2015/2016   August        21    Friday   17:30:00   Hobro  Nordsjaelland    1       3       A          1               1              4
Denmark Superliga   2015/2016   August        30    Sunday   19:30:00   Midtjylland    Hobro    2       0       H          7               3                                   4
```

Note: In the previous example only games relationated to Hobro team are showed.

My problem is when I want to add total points per team. In a match (row) I have HomeTeamPoints and AwayTeamPoints. I can not find the way I can group by HomeTeam and add the points from the last time that team was AwayTeam(and vice versa).

I have managed to get total points by creating two tables and filtering by team name. This gives me the current classification of the League but it does not help me to put in a database where there are more seasons.

My goal is that the total points are updated every week grouping by season and team and work for past seasons.

Answer (score 0):

My advise is to use the below as it is the least messy and keeps your data tidy:

```
library(stringr)


League$HomeTeamTotalPoints <- League$HomeTeam == "Hobro"

League$AwayTeamTotalPoints <- League$AwayTeam == "Hobro"

League$HomeTeamTotalPoints <- gsub("FALSE", " ", League$HomeTeamTotalPoints )

League$AwayTeamTotalPoints <- gsub("FALSE", " ", League$AwayTeamTotalPoints )
```

After that simply replace the "TRUE" with their respective numeric value from the home and away team columns